# windows8 how to support multiple screen sizes of same Resolution

Tags: windows-8

I have designed one page for my windows 8 application which has to run on same Resolution with different screen sizes. for example consider i am having 10.6 inch tablet(1366*768) and Desktop of 23 inch(1366*768) my application should support both Screen sizes.iam using c# and xaml to develop the application. can anybody help me. thanks

Comment: Considering it is even the same resolution, it should automatically fit it regardless of display size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test various resolutions and screen sizes using the Visual Studio simulator.  In the Run dropdown menu with the green play button, select "Simulator" (it is probably currently set to "Local Machine").  Then click the Run button to start the simulator.  When the simulator launches running your code, select the 8th button down that looks like a monitor.  (The tooltip for this button is "Change resolution").  That will give you multiple screen sizes/resolutions that you can test at.

In additional, here are some useful [guidelines for scaling to screens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465349).  This calls out some coding best practices to scale your app across different resolutions/screen sizes well.  Specifically, check out the [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br229771) and [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br211837) controls; they can help scale a fixed or adaptive layout, respectively.  And a [canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465734) scales images nicely.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. which is the best resolution of the slices i can make use of to scale perfectly in all the resolutions. or do we need to maintain different resolution of images. I have seen we are using scale-100,scale-140,scale-180 for different resolutions. can we make use of only one resolution that fit for all. please suggest me.. Thanks

Comment: You can just provide the scale-100, and it will automatically scale that image for you.  It just may look a little grainy at high resolutions.  Examples of how the resource manager chooses which to use are given at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552943.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx.